# Unable to fill data grid view dynamically using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms, sql-server-2012

I'm writing a program using C# win forms and SQL Server 2012. In one of my forms I have a combobox a button and a datagrid view. I want the data grid view to be filled every time I change the value in combo box.

This code doesn't work :( (it does not return an error)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString());
        //int idc = 100;
        DataSet ptDataset = new DataSet();
        string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["secaloFormulaCS"].ToString(); 
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(con);
        sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spDispProductInfo", sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        da.Fill(ptDataset);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = ptDataset;
        sqlCon.Close();
 }
```

Comment: make sure that you are binding the combo box on `(!Page.IsPostBack)` condition only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString());
    //int idc = 100;
    DataSet ptDataset = new DataSet();
    string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["secaloFormulaCS"].ToString(); 
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(con);
    sqlCon.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spDispProductInfo", sqlCon);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
    da.Fill(ptDataset);
    dataGridView2.DataSource =  ptDataset.Tables[0];
    sqlCon.Close();
```

Comment: IF you really only need one `DataTable` - why use a `DataSet` and then reference `ptDataset.Tables[0]` ?? Just use a `DataTable` from the beginning - much less overhead!

Answer (score 0):

You must Use the Event of your comboBox `clik` not the button.
Just try to add this `button1_click` event to the combobox that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Set your Code in `SelectedIndexChanged` event Of your comboBox

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ptDataset = new DataSet();
            string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["secaloFormulaCS"].ToString();
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(con);
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spDispProductInfo", sqlCon);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString()));
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            da.Fill(ptDataset);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ptDataset;
            sqlCon.Close();

        }
```